# Why don't they use 4-point formula to approximate derivative of a function

Tags: numerical-methods

I am currently taking a numerical analysis course, whose main reference is the book "Numerical Analysis" by Richard L. Burden and J. Douglas Faires

I am preparing for a presentation about numerical differentiation. One of the main reference is the section 4.1 of the prementioned book. The authors did mention about 2-points, 3-points and 5-points formulae used to approximate derivatives. However, I still have no idea why they didn't mention 4-points formulae. These are also a special case of the general $(n+1)-$point formula. Why aren't they mentioning about them? Is it because that the 4-points formulae can't be applied as well as the 2,3 and 5 do?

Any help is properly appreciated.

Comment: It would be good to add which derivatives you are trying to approximate. Is it $f'$ or higher order derivatives. Confirm if you step size is uniform.

Comment: This text: http://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/textbook-9th_edition.pdf

Comment: It looks to me like the n+1 case is given so that you can derive any you'd like. And then they give 2 examples.

Comment: Or are you saying that they don't mention the n+1 case?

Comment: It's given on page 176. Equation 4.2

Comment: I'm trying to approximate the first derivative. I'm talking about the case where $n = 3$ (4 points formulae). The authors didn't mention about them in the textbook. I'm wondering if there is a particular reason